# GGplot2 error in check_aesthetics after log variable conversion

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm practicing with this database:
https://studysites.uk.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20Data%20Files/Chapter%205/DownloadFestival(No%20Outlier).dat

I'm trying to plot the density histogram with overlapped a theoretical normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation

Since data is skewed, I tried a log(1+x) transformation:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library("tidyverse", "here", "magrittr")

dlf<-here::here("data/DownloadFestival(No Outlier).dat") %>% readr::read_delim(col_names = TRUE)
```

```
day2log<-na.omit(log1p(dlf$day2))
day2log<-as.numeric(day2log)
glimpse(day2log)
hist.day2log<-ggplot2::ggplot(dlf, aes(day2log)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour = "#76b81b", fill = "blue" ) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(day2log), sd = sd(day2log)), colour = "black", size = 2) +
  labs( x = "Hygiene score day 2log", y = "Density day2log") +
  theme_minimal()
  
hist.day2log
```

The error I get is the following:

```
num [1:264] 0.854 0.88 0.077 0.365 0.182 ...
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (810): x
Backtrace:
 1. base `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2 by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2 f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2 f(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
 Error in check_aesthetics(evaled, n) :
```

I tried to check the day2log variable and It looks ok:

```
glimpse(day2log)
 num [1:264] 0.854 0.88 0.077 0.365 0.182 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have removed the `NA` values from `day2`, so the vector `day2log` is now shorter than `dlf`, which is the data frame you are passing into `ggplot`. Since `ggplot` expects any external vectors (ie vectors that are not columns in the passed data frame) to be either the same length as the data frame, or of length 1, you get an error.

To solve it, do your calculations directly on `day2`. You can explicitly remove `NA` values where they need to be removed, such as inside `mean` and `sd`

```r
ggplot(dlf, aes(log1p(day2))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour = "#76b81b", fill = "blue" ) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                args = list(mean = mean(log1p(dlf$day2), na.rm = TRUE), 
                            sd   = sd(log1p(dlf$day2), na.rm = TRUE)), 
                colour = "black", size = 2) +
  labs( x = "Hygiene score day 2log", y = "Density day2log") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]